# Unit Testing - dependency injection zf2

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework2

In one of controller I have following code to send email and sms using dependency injection. which works fine

```
                $message = new \Application\SendMessage\Message();

                $message->toName = $toName; 
                $message->toEmail = $toEmail; 
                $message->fromEmail = $fromemail;
                $message->emailBodyText = $emailBodyText;
                $message->smsMessage = $emailBodyText;
                $message->toMobile = $toMobile;


                $seSMS = new \Application\SendMessage\SendSMS($message);    
                $suSMS = new \Application\SendMessage\SendMessage($seSMS);
                $statusMsg = $suSMS->releaseMsg();

                $seEmail = new \Application\SendMessage\SendEmail($message);
                $suEmail = new \Application\SendMessage\SendMessage($seEmail);
                $statusMsgEmail = $suEmail->releaseMsg();
```

and I am testing it, using following code

```
public function testcreateActionCanBeAccessed() 
{

    $postData = array(
        // variables here
    );

    $this->dispatch('/mycontroller/myaction', 'POST', $postData);
    $this->assertResponseStatusCode(200);
}
```

Which works fine and give me 100 percent code coverage, Only problem is, every time I run unit test, it sends the email and release the sms text message as well. which is good sometimes, as it also tests email sending and text messaging feature.

But if you have to run your test again and again it is kind of annoying, How can I mock above code so it will still give me 100 percent code coverage but will not send sms text and email.

Comment: Well making a condition for the request to not come through console is one way to tackle it, assuming that action is not 'normally' invoked from console. I'm curious myself whether there is another way.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to utilize the "Service Locator Pattern" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern

Instead of:

```
$message = new \Application\SendMessage\Message();
```

You would have something like:

```
$message = $service_locator->new('Application\SendMessage\Message');
```

In your test, you could then utilize mocking (http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/test-doubles.html) to return "dummy" messages/sendmessages that don't actually send an email, but still ensure the proper methods get called.